# Selecting by location AND attribute using one query

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-pro, select-by-attribute, select-by-location

I am using ArcMap 10.8 and ArcGIS Pro 2.7

I have two feature classes: one containing currently uploaded county address points (cad_n) and the other containing updated county address points (d_n). A large majority of these points are the same, but slightly offset. In order to create a single feature class containing a combined, full set of data, I am trying to delete overlapping points from the cad_n file.

I have a Python code that first selects features from cad_n that are within 500 feet of d_n features, and then selects a subset of those features that share an address with d_n:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/carson.jones/Desktop/Data/DRIZCAD.gdb"


locq = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('cad_n', 'WITHIN_A_DISTANCE', 'd_n', '500 Feet')

locattq = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(locq, 'SUBSET_SELECTION', 'T_Address IN (SELECT T_Address FROM d_n)')
```

While this is close to what I want, I would rather make a selection of cad_n features within a distance of a d_n feature that has an identical address.

Is there a way to combine these queries into one selection?

Comment: As you can see, they are two completely different functions (or tools).  There is no way to include a attribute "where" clause in the spatial selection, and no way to include a location definition in the attribute selection (apart from some very basic `SHAPE@...` selections, I suppose).  I suspect that if anybody (including youfself) developed a function or tool to both, then internally it would likely use both of those functions anyhow.  If it's something you want to do often, then just create your own new function that calls both of those existing functions.